# jquery FullCalendar - delete all events in a selection

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and I'm using the select: function to allow the user to select one or more days, and then enter a value, which I will later save to a database. I want to clear the existing events in the selection before adding a new one, but I can't access the event property from within select function to then call fullCalendar('removeEvent', );. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The FullCalendar plugin provides a method `clientEvents` which returns all events that are stored locally at the client (e.g. if the calendar retrieves the data from a json feed, you only get those events that already got downloaded). As you cannot select something that is not visible, all events in the selected area are definitely in this cache. See http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/ for more information.

This method accepts an optional parameter `idOrFilter`, used to apply a filter before returning the events. This can be a list of IDs or (more valuable to you) a function. This function gets an event object and returns true (meaning: include this event in the result set) or false (discard it).

```
var eventsToDelete = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
    // check if event.start >= selection.start && event.start < selection.end ... etc.
});
```

`eventsToDelete` is now an array that contains all the events you want to delete.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on this? I am having the same problem but I don't understand how to do what your saying. Possibly more code? :) Thanks!